Installed correct version of panda DataReader but seem to be getting an error when I get stock data
I am using Jupyter Lab to run some code. The code that I am running is:
aapl = data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
aapl

The error I am getting is the following:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 1
----> 1 aapl = data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
      2 aapl

File /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:213, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    211         raise TypeError(msg)
    212     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 213 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py:379, in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, api_key)
    367     raise NotImplementedError(msg)
    369 if data_source == "yahoo":
    370     return YahooDailyReader(
    371         symbols=name,
    372         start=start,
    373         end=end,
    374         adjust_price=False,
    375         chunksize=25,
    376         retry_count=retry_count,
    377         pause=pause,
    378         session=session,
--> 379     ).read()
    381 elif data_source == "iex":
    382     return IEXDailyReader(
    383         symbols=name,
    384         start=start,
   (...)
    390         session=session,
    391     ).read()

File /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py:253, in _DailyBaseReader.read(self)
    251 # If a single symbol, (e.g., 'GOOG')
    252 if isinstance(self.symbols, (string_types, int)):
--> 253     df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
    254 # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
    255 elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):

File /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py:152, in YahooDailyReader._read_one_data(self, url, params)
    150 ptrn = r"root\.App\.main = (.*?);\n}\(this\)\);"
    151 try:
--> 152     j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
    153     data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
    154 except KeyError:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
I only installed DataReader, and then after the error came up I made sure to update the latest version of DataReader but the same error came through after executing the above code.

When asking a question, it's a good idea to provide a minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . I've added some missing pieces in my answer.

Reproducing the error:

In your stack trace I see python 3.12, so I've used python 3.12.3
pip install pandas-datareader
pip install setuptools is also required to avoid a distutils error

Then I can reproduce your error by running
from pandas_datareader import data
from datetime import datetime

start_date = datetime(2016, 9, 1)
end_date = datetime(2018, 9, 1)

aapl = data.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", start_date, end_date)

Cause(s)
It looks like there are several problems upstream:

Yahoo has moved to a paid model for finance data, you will likely need to pay and use an API key. See this issue and this page from Yahoo. However, this may not be your only problem, because...
No new releases of the pandas-datareader package for 3 years. There is no roadmap for new release and tests are failing for the yahoo reader.

A Solution
To get free yahoo data, you can use yfinance
pip install yfinance
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

symbol = 'WIRE'
data = yf.Ticker(symbol) 
ts = data.history(start='2021-01-01', end='2023-12-31')
df = pd.DataFrame(ts) 
df

If you'd like to try continuing to use pandas-datareader despite it not really being maintained anymore, here's a hack from the yfinance maintainer:
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf

yf.pdr_override()  # <== that's all it takes :-)

# download dataframe using pandas_datareader
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("SPY", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")

This works, but gives the warning
yfinance: pandas_datareader support is deprecated & semi-broken so will be removed in a future verison. Just use yfinance.

So probably in the long run you want to just use yfinance or use another library.
A more verbose, but specific solution
yf.pdr_override() probably changes more than what you want to change with data.DataReader from pandas-datareader, so here is a solution that is more verbose, but only changes exactly what you want to change:
from pandas_datareader import data
from datetime import datetime
from yfinance.multi import download


from functools import wraps


def override_yahoo_behavior(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Extract the data_source parameter from the kwargs
        data_source = kwargs.get("data_source")

        # If data_source is not provided in kwargs, check args
        if data_source is None and len(args) > 1:
            data_source = args[1]

        # Check if the data_source is "yahoo" and return the custom behavior
        if data_source == "yahoo":
            # get the name, start, and end date from the kwargs or args
            name = kwargs.get("name")
            start_date = kwargs.get("start")
            end_date = kwargs.get("end")

            # If not in kwargs, check args
            if name is None and len(args) > 0:
                name = args[0]
            if start_date is None and len(args) > 2:
                start_date = args[2]
            if end_date is None and len(args) > 3:
                end_date = args[3]

            return download(tickers=name, start=start_date, end=end_date)

        # Otherwise, call the original function
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


start_date = datetime(2016, 9, 1)
end_date = datetime(2018, 9, 1)

# Apply the wrapper to the DataReader function
data.DataReader = override_yahoo_behavior(data.DataReader)

aapl = data.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", start_date, end_date)

Basically, we just check if the data source is "yahoo" and if so, call the correct yfinance function with the correct args. Otherwise, don't modify anything else about data.DataReader (in case you want to use other data sources).

Thank you very much for your help. I don't mind paying for the data, but if this error  persists does that mean nothing can be done to fix at as there are no new releases to patch these errors?

Added a working solution, you can see my edit above. In the long run, I'd probably suggest not using pandas-datareader unless it starts being maintained again. yfinance provides a fix, but even they say they don't expect to maintain this fix anymore, because pandas-datareader is too broken unfortunately.
